# Connection between fixed points of $(x,y) \mapsto (p,q) \in k[x,y]^2$ and its corresponding map $ (a,b) \mapsto (p(a,b),q(a,b)) : k^2 \to k^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $p=p(x,y),q=q(x,y) \in k[x,y]$.
Let $F: k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ be defined by $F: (x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ and let $f: k^2 \to k^2$ be its corresponding map, namely the map defined by $f: (a,b) \mapsto (p(a,b),q(a,b))$, $a,b \in k$.

> What is the connection between (non-constant) fixed points of $F$ and fixed points of $f$?

BTW, if, in addition, the Jacobian of $p$ and $q$, $p_xq_y-p_yq_x$, is a non-zero constant, then there is a nice result that if $F$ has a fixed point, then $F$ is an automorphism, see [Kraft's paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242434791_On_a_Question_of_Yosef_Stein) and [Shpilrain and yu's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/118162?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: $F$ has always fixed points, namely the constants. I assume you meant  non-constant. There are no easy relation between the fixed points of $F$ and $f$. As you are aware, for most such questions, one would assume $p,q$ have no constant terms and then $f$ fixes the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Indeed, by a fixed point of $F$ I meant a polynomial of degree $ \geq 1$.

Comment: (I hoped that perhaps there exists a nice theorem in algebraic geometry that would help).